# "NOT" operator for MATCH in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In Neo4j 2.x, it is easy to find all nodes with a certain value for a given property using Cypher 2.0, like so:

```
MATCH (node {property: 'value'}) 
RETURN node;
```

**However, how would I find all nodes with any value for `property` except for `"value"`?** I tried using the `NOT` operator like so, but this simply returns a syntax error:

```
MATCH (node {property: NOT 'value'}) 
RETURN node;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The concise syntax for properties in the MATCH clause only works with exact matches.

If you want to do any other kind of match condition, you should the WHERE clause:

```
MATCH (node)
WHERE node.property <> 'value'
RETURN node;
```

Another example:

```
MATCH (node)
WHERE NOT node.property IN ["red", "blue", "yellow"]
RETURN node;
```

Please note this will do an entire graph scan, which is strongly discouraged. On any reasonable dataset size, this query might not complete or at least not in a timely fashion.

Comment: Thanks! My dataset is reasonably small (~50000 nodes), and my goal was just to get the number of nodes without the specific value for the property. The query executed in ~350ms, so it looks like Neo4j could handle the query for my DB size :)

Comment: @ShreyGupta how do you define "small"?